# Drag and lock inside of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Online sample http://jsfiddle.net/dhCLd/

A simple drag magnify,

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.drag = function(opt) {

        opt = $.extend({
            handle: "",
            cursor:"move"}, opt);

        if(opt.handle === "") {
            var $el = this;
        } else {
            var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
        }

        return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
            if(opt.handle === "") {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
            } else {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
            }
            var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
                native_width = 0,
                native_height = 0;


            $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents('.magnify').on("mousemove", function(e) {

                if(!native_width && !native_height){
                    var image_object = new Image();
                    image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");
                    native_width = image_object.width;
                    native_height = image_object.height;
                }else{
                    var magnify_offset = $drag.parents('.magnify').offset();
                    var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
                    var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;
                    var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*native_width - $drag.width()/2)*-1;
                    var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*native_height - $drag.height()/2)*-1;
                    var px = mx - $(".large").width()/2;
                    var py = my - $(".large").height()/2;
                    var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";  



                  $('.draggable').css({left:px, top:py, backgroundPosition: bgp}).on("mouseup", function() {
                      $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
                  });
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
            if(opt.handle === "") {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

How can I make the "magnify" stops at the edges around the .small` image, if outside of the image then undraggable. If someone could help?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this:http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/dhCLd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just limit the values of `mx` (in range `[0,magnify's width]`) and `my` (in range `[0, magnify's height]`):

```
var magnify = $drag.closest('.magnify');
var magnify_offset = magnify.offset();
var mx = Math.min(Math.max(e.pageX - magnify_offset.left,0),magnify.width());
var my = Math.min(Math.max(e.pageY - magnify_offset.top,0), magnify.height());
```

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/dhCLd/2/).

Comment: Nice idea! Although it requires more calculations.

Comment: a Much better solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 what calculations do you mean? this is dynamic enough, of course the inner background image should fit the `magnify`.

Comment: By calculations I mean the `Math.min` and `Math.max` comparisons. But anyway your answer is definitely better mine. (I just make it stops because I don't have to type that much)

Comment: In fact the inner edge of the phone does not coincide with the edge of the image, we have to calculate these offsets by using some image editor (such as paint) or simply using trial and error method until the result is OK, so the ranges are `[5, magnify's width - 5]` and `[4, magnify's height - 3]`, here is the updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/dhCLd/4/

Answer (score 1):

To make the magnifying glass undraggable when it's outside a bounded area, simply test the position of the background image as it is being drag:

```
var cH = 175/2;                                              //Half of the magnifying glass
if(rx > cH|| ry > cH || rx < -579 + cH || ry < -1107 + cH){  //579 and 1107 are the dimension of the background image
    $(this).trigger("mouseup");                              //Make it undraggable
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks,just realized position/numbers are not dynamic, I will make it dynamic :-)